# Transfer data from factory to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Somehow I am not able to get my data from the factory method to the controller. I am using javascript remoting and factory is given below

```
function userRecordFetchFactory($rootScope) {
        var custRec = {};   
            return {                                        
                checkRecordType : function(urlObject) {
                 function loadRecordType(err, records, event) {
                        if (err) {
                            displayReadingInformationErrorView();
                        } else if (records != null && records.length == 0) {
                            displayReadingInformationErrorView();
                        } else {
                             custRec = {
                                Name : records[0].get('Name'),
                                lat : records[0].get('Latitude__c'),
                                lon : records[0].get('Longitude__c'),
                                SiteStreet : records[0]
                                        .get('SiteStreet__c'),
                                SiteCity : records[0].get('SiteCity__c'),
                                SiteCountryCode : records[0]
                                        .get('SiteCountryCode__c'),
                                SitePostalCode : records[0]
                                        .get('SitePostalCode__c'),
                                AddressID : records[0].get('AddressID__c'),
                                loaded : true
                            };

                        }
                    }
                    if (urlObject && urlObject.aid
                            && urlObject.aid.startsWith(accPrefix)) {
                        objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Account();
                    }
                    if (urlObject && urlObject.aid
                            && urlObject.aid.startsWith(leadPrefix)) {
                        objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Lead();
                    }

                    if (objModel) {
                        objModel.retrieve({
                            where : {
                                Id : {
                                    eq : urlObject.aid
                                }
                            }
                        }, loadRecordType);
                    }

                    return custRec;
                }
            };
        }
```

and my controller is given below to access the data

```
function LocatorInitController($document, $scope,
                userRecordFetchFactory) {
                console.log("inside the controller"+urlParams);
                $scope.CustomerSite = {};
                userRecordFetchFactory.checkRecordType(urlParams)
                .then(function successData(data){
                $scope.CustomerSite = data.data;
                execGeoCoding();
                });
```

I get an error cannot read property success of undefined. In the factory the method checkRecordType has a retrieve function which is a javascript remoting call and that finction has a callback to loadrecordtype.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you write your factory in a  simpler way to read it. All your nesting is causing you not to see the whole thing easily

Put all the accessible members up top

```
// pass functions as references to object properties
// can easily see the whole factory object at top of the file
var custRec = {
  checkRecordType : checkRecordType,
  subscribe       : subscribe    
};

return custRec;


// move function declarations to the bottom and out of the way

function checkRecordType(){
    /// do stuff
    return stuff;
}

function loadRecordType(err, records, event) {
   /// do stuff
    return stuff;
}

function subscribe(scope, callback){
   /// do stuff
    return stuff;
}
```

See [John Papa Angular STyle Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y052)

Comment: loadRecordType cannot be out of the checkRecordType. Plus you can remove the subscribe function as it is of no need. Still I am having trouble to get data to the controller.

Comment: but why not? Also you should never pass scope into a service

Comment: loadRecordType is a way to get data in salesforce using javascript remoting. So if you look into the Retrieve function in checkRecordType that is what calls loadRecordType. hence it cannot be outside the checkrecordtype

Comment: that doesn't make sense. Don't think you are understanding javascript scope properly. Irregardless you have all sorts of problems other than that to worry about and creating a proper clean structure will help

Comment: also get rid of using `success` it is deprecated...get used to using promise `then()`

Comment: okay I have refactored the code and put .then now my error says userRecordFetchFactory.checkRecordType(...).then is not a function

Comment: create a demo that reproduces this.... you aren't returning a promise from that function is always the reason why `then()` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try rewriting your factory like so:

```
function Factory() {
var custRec = {

    subscribe: function(scope, callback) {
        var handler = $rootScope.$on(
            'fire-event-accountservice-retrieve',
            function(
                event, data) {
                callback(data);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
    },
    checkRecordType: function(urlObject) {
        var custRec;
        if (urlObject.aid == null && urlObject.addr == null) {
            displayCurrentLocation();
        }
        if (urlObject && urlObject.aid &&
            urlObject.aid.startsWith(accPrefix)) {
            objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Account();
        }
        if (urlObject && urlObject.aid &&
            urlObject.aid.startsWith(leadPrefix)) {
            objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Lead();
        }
        if (objModel == null && urlObject.aid != null && urlObject.addr == null) {
            displayReadingInformationErrorView();
        }
        if (objModel) {
            objModel.retrieve({
                where: {
                    Id: {
                        eq: urlObject.aid
                    }
                }
            }, loadRecordType);
        } else if ((urlObject.addr != null || urlObject.addr != '') && (typeof urlObject.addr != "undefined")) {
            displayLocationBasedOnAddress(urlObject.addr);
        }

        function loadRecordType(err, records, event) {
            if (err) {
                displayReadingInformationErrorView();
            } else if (records != null && records.length == 0) {
                displayReadingInformationErrorView();
            } else {
                custRec = {
                    Name: records[0].get('Name'),
                    lat: records[0].get('Latitude__c'),
                    lon: records[0].get('Longitude__c'),
                    SiteStreet: records[0]
                        .get('SiteStreet__c'),
                    SiteCity: records[0].get('SiteCity__c'),
                    SiteCountryCode: records[0]
                        .get('SiteCountryCode__c'),
                    SitePostalCode: records[0]
                        .get('SitePostalCode__c'),
                    AddressID: records[0].get('AddressID__c'),
                    loaded: true
                };

                /*  $rootScope.$emit(
                            'fire-event-accountservice-retrieve',
                            custRec); */
            }
        }

    }
}
return custRec;
}
```

Looks like you're returning your factory object the wrong way.

Comment: okay I have refactored the code and put .then now my error says userRecordFetchFactory.checkRecordType(...).then is not a function

Comment: The .then implies your client is expecting a promise.  Just from a brief overview of checkRecordType, it doesn't look like a promise is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
function userRecordFetchFactory($rootScope) {
var custRec = {};

    custRec.checkRecordType = function (urlObject) {
        function loadRecordType(err, records, event) {
            if (err) {
                displayReadingInformationErrorView();
            } else if (records != null && records.length == 0) {
                displayReadingInformationErrorView();
            } else {
                custRec = {
                    Name: records[0].get('Name'),
                    lat: records[0].get('Latitude__c'),
                    lon: records[0].get('Longitude__c'),
                    SiteStreet: records[0]
                        .get('SiteStreet__c'),
                    SiteCity: records[0].get('SiteCity__c'),
                    SiteCountryCode: records[0]
                        .get('SiteCountryCode__c'),
                    SitePostalCode: records[0]
                        .get('SitePostalCode__c'),
                    AddressID: records[0].get('AddressID__c'),
                    loaded: true
                };

            }
        }
        if (urlObject && urlObject.aid
            && urlObject.aid.startsWith(accPrefix)) {
            objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Account();
        }
        if (urlObject && urlObject.aid
            && urlObject.aid.startsWith(leadPrefix)) {
            objModel = new RemoteObjectModel.Lead();
        }

        if (objModel) {
            objModel.retrieve({
                where: {
                    Id: {
                        eq: urlObject.aid
                    }
                }
            }, 
return custRec;
}
```